# Assigning to "id<Delegate>" from incompatible type Class __strong

Tags: objective-c

In the following code, delegating a method to `UIView` subclass.
But, the error `Assigning to "id<Delegate>" from imcompatible type Class __strong` occurs.

How do I fix it to run `-delegateMethod`?

ViewController.h

```
@protocol MyDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)delegateMethod;
@end

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    CustomView *customView = [[CustomView alloc]init];
    self.delegate = customView; //Assigning to "id<Delegate>" from imcompatible type Class __strong
    [self.view addSubview:customView];
}
```

CustomView.h

```
@interface CustomView : UIView
```

CustomView.m

```
@interface CustomView () <MyDelegate>

- (void)delegateMethod {
    NSLog(@"succeeded");
}
```

OtherViewController.m

```
@interface OtherViewController () <MyDelegate>

- (void)aMethod {
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    vc.delegate = self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify explicitly that your `CustomView` class conforms to `DetailDelegate` protocol, just implementing required method is not enough for compiler:

```
@interface CustomView : UIView<DetailDelegate>
```

Comment: @kusumoto_teruya, you need to put that declaration in the header file that will be imported in your controller class (from the code you posted it seems that you added `<DetailDelegate>` part into .m file)

Answer (score 0):

In **OtherViewController.h** add/ change

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface CustomView: UIView <DetailDelegate>
```